# TVS protection burnt too easily

Tags: solid-state-relay, esd, circuit-protection, tvs, transient-suppression

It's about an year that I'm using TVS diodes to suppress spikes from the AC motors (240V - max 240W) that drives my roller shutters and protect the solid state relay that actuate the motor.
What is unpleasant is that I got a diode failure every few months (at least 2 times a year).

Is there something I can change to avoid this kind of hardware failures?

At the moment this is my configuration:

[image: schematic diagram]

TVS diode is a 1.5KE440CA so 1.5kW power dissipation, 376V working voltage, 418V breakdown voltage, 776V clamping voltage.

The relay is a SSR-40DA (40A, 380V)

Comment: You should consider activating the SSR when the supply voltage is at a peak value in order to avoid large saturation currents that exceed the maximum peak current (2.5 A) of the TVS. This is the normal method when driving inductive loads. You haven't specified the motor type hence this is a comment.

Comment: @Andyaka The motor is a simple AC single-phase asynchronous motor!

Comment: Use a higher rated TVS such that the clamp voltage is still less than breakdown voltage